# Car won't start sometimes

Tags: honda, starting, accord

I have a 1996 Honda Accord. It always starts on the first try everyday. It's after I turn the car off it won't restart sometimes. If I sit and wait 2-3 minutes, it will restart. What could be the issue here?

Comment: when it doesn't start can you hear the fuel pump run? The older Hondas are known to have fuel pump relay issues when hot.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the specifics of your Honda, here are my thoughts:

Hot-starts need the fuel rail to be pressurized. If the fuel pump is unable to build up sufficient pressure then the engine will struggle to run. Have the fuel rail pressure tested to confirm that fuel rail pressure is up to spec.

***Note that lack of fuel pressure does not guarantee that the fuel pump is bad.***

As @mikes said in his comment, a bad fuel pump relay could be preventing the fuel pump from activating and pressurizing the fuel line.

It could also be that a fuel injector is stuck open by fine debris which is preventing pressure build-up, or a fine crack in the fuel rail.

Given that the engine starts over after a couple of minutes though, it is likely that the hot relay is at fault more than a mechanical issue.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, check the fuel pump relay first. Then have a mechanic test the Crankshaft Position Sensor. It is located behind the timing belt and requires removal of the accessory drives and timing covers.

[See it here](http://i133.photobucket.com/albums/q71/GhostAccord/Odds-n-sodds/TDC-CKP-Sensor.jpg)